# Package not found despite being installed on Linux

Tags: texlive, installing, linux, paths, debian

I am trying to us the `extarticle.cls` class but when I compile I get an error saying it cannot be found.

`! LaTeX Error: File 'extarticle.cls' not found.`

Since I am using a Debian based system I checked what package the class comes with and it is bundled in the `texlive-latex-recommended` package. Which I confirmed was installed.

```
apt list texlive* --installed
Listing... Done
texlive-base/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-bibtex-extra/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-3 all [installed]
texlive-binaries/groovy,now 2020.20200327.54578-4build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
texlive-extra-utils/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-3 all [installed]
texlive-fonts-recommended/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-base/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-recommended/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-2 all [installed]
texlive-luatex/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-plain-generic/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-3 all [installed,automatic]
texlive/groovy,groovy,now 2020.20200804-2 all [installed]
```

I then looked up the files and confirmed that the files have read permissions.

```
ls -l /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes/
total 140
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2201 Jan 12  2006 autopagewidth.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20602 Jan 12  2006 extarticle.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23153 Jan 12  2006 extbook.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14088 Jan 12  2006 extletter.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2573 Jan 12  2006 extproc.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23786 Jan 12  2006 extreport.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3240 Jan 12  2006 extsizes.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6214 Jan 12  2006 size14.clo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6192 Jul 16  2007 size17.clo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6196 Jul 16  2007 size20.clo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6172 Jan 12  2006 size8.clo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6172 Jan 12  2006 size9.clo
```

I assume there is something wrong with the PATH texlive is using to look for files but I don't know how. What should I do to point texlive in the right direction?

Texlive version:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.02
```

Operating system:

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="20.10"
ID=pop
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
```

Log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.3.6)  9 JUN 2021 17:53 entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**template.tex
(./template.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

! LaTeX Error: File `extarticle.cls' not found.
```

Comment: show the start of the log, what path does it use for `article.cls` ?

Comment: I have added the beginning of the log

Comment: sorry my fault, I didn't ask the question I meant to ask. If you try the same with `\documentclass{article}` does it show `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls` or a different path?  if it is that path you could try `sudo mktexlsr`  and force it to regenerate the filename files

Comment: It is pointing to `home/gthomson/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`. This must be a second `Tex` installation that must have occurred with installing an `R` package sometime in the past. I uninstalled this package and if I call `/usr/bin/pdflatex` I can find the `extarticle.cls` package.

Comment: bingo:-)  I suspected two tex installations:-)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)